# Android: unable to lauch new Activity from an inner class

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Android: someone help:
I notice this kind of question has been asked before by other people but the answers have not been useful to my my case; I need to launch a new activity from an inner
class but all I get is the error bellow:

```
04-05 15:00:43.851: E/AndroidRuntime(3288): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.school.School$StudentProfile
```

Here is my code snippet:

```
public class School extends Activity{
ProgressDialogue progressDialogue;

protected WebViewTask _webTask;

String path = "http://www.school.com/student/"; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.school);


    progressDialogue = new ProgressDialogue(School.this);

    _webTask = new WebViewTask();
    _webTask.execute();

}   

//rest of the code

  /** The inner class */

public class StudentProfile {
    Context context;


    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */

    public StudentProfile(Context c) {
         context=c;
        }

    /** launch student activity */
    public void lauchProfile() {

         School.this.startActivity(new Intent(School.this, StudentProfile.class));
        //Intent intent = new Intent(School.this, StudentProfile.class);

        //startActivity(intent);

    }
}   

void webView(){
    String url = path +"student.php";   

    WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.trivia_webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    wv.addJavascriptInterface(new StudentProfile (this), "Student");

    wv.loadUrl(url);

    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // open URL in the web view itself
            if (url.contains(url))
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            // open URL in an external web browser
            else {

                return true;
            }
        }
    });
}

// rest of the code
```

NOTE: there is a 'student' button on the web view that is supposed to launch the StudentProfile activity.

Comment: Change School.this to context in your StudentProfile class.

Comment: from where you are calling "StudentProfile(Context c)" constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `StudentProfile` is not an `Activity`, so you can not start it that way. It needs to be a separate class, and declared in `AndroidManifest.xml`.